# how to UNSELECT row in a ttk.Treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Once I click into a `ttk.Treeview()` and select a row, I can click another row but there is no way for me to `UNSELECT` all the rows, there will always be at least 1 row selected. is there a clever way to allow unselecting the last selected row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the name of your var i use `treeview=ttk.Treeview()` and  put in a button `[UNSELECT ALL]` the following code:

```
treeview.selection_clear()
```

Comment: What does it actually do? Because it's inherited from `tkinter.Misc` there's no mention of this method in [the Treeview docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm). [This](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html) great reference also says nothing about it. I have trouble getting it to work. Does it require a `ttk.Treeview` object to have focus to work? The Python shell help says only: *Clear the current X selection*. What does `X` stand for, coordinates?