# How to deselect an item (or items) of a Tkinter ttk.Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm having trouble trying to deselect a `Treeview` item while doing it from a callback of another widget. I managed to implement a working deselection on <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> press with:

```
tree.selection_remove(tree.focus())
```

in a callback bound to a treeview object itself. It works only when the treeview has focus (but it's OK, that's a desired behavior). On the other hand trying the same from a callback of another widget doesn't work.

I tried using:

```
tree.selection_clear()
```

as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376198/how-to-unselect-row-in-a-ttk-treeview-in-tkinter/45376931), but this does not work either.

**Important**: selecting items in the treeview from the same call with `tree.selection_add(iid)` works. The same as manipulating yet another widget (a combobox, and the widget doing the call is a frame). Based on this, I don't suppose the problem is due to some silly bug (a typo or something like that) in my code.

My theory is being out of focus is a problem as it's the only difference I see between when the same code works with <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> but not elsewhere, so I tried to gain focus with `tree.focus_set()` and `tree.focus_force()`, but that didn't change anything.

I don't quite understand what `selection_clear()` is supposed to do. As `ttk.Treeview` inherits this method from `ttk.Misc` the documentation on this is scarse. I couldn't find anything on it [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm) or [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html). The only thing I found is a laconic:

> Clear the current X selection.

from the Python shell help (what's the cryptic `X`, coordinates?)

So how to accomplish so seemingly simple? Please help, I'm at a loss for ideas.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Nae: That was uncalled for. I asked a general question, only giving a specific example to better illustrate it. **I wasn't asking for debugging my code not providing one**. The only behavior you're gonna "moderate" aka enforce that way will be people deliberately axing useful details from their questions. Ponder if it's really what you're after. In my case, I was hoping for a simple answer like: *yes, selection_clear() is how you deselect treeview items() - look at your code, something's amiss*. That would be a great help and I'm sure there are many nice people here happy to provide it.

Comment: Sure, but how is _not_ providing a sample code helping?

Comment: Very simple. I don't provide a code to debug, for the very reason that I don't want anybody to debug it. The question is *How to deselect a Treeview item*. That's as general as you can get.

Comment: @o'rety, please don't get me wrong, I even understand your point about posing the question this way, but think about this: you could have just used the very same title and posted minimal code just to create, select and insert an item. That way nobody feels like just writing code for you, and you avoid making a report of your rationale, that forces others to make requirement analysis, introducing four layers of possible errors: your rationale, your code (that nobody sees), something in the text you wrote about it, and finally somewhere in the analysis others make of your words.

Comment: Also your question is quite specific, not a general one, which is good for posting in SO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK. So the answer was:

```
ttk.Treeview.selection()
```

It's not listed in [the great New Mexico Tech resource](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html), but it does get mentioned in [the best tutorial out there](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) and (of course) is in [the docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm). Somehow it still escaped me.

Now, having a way to test contents of a selection it was easy:

```
if len(tree.selection()) > 0:
    tree.selection_remove(tree.selection()[0])
```

Answer (score 10):

What about:

```
for item in self.tree.selection():
   self.tree.selection_remove(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer that [z33k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2238519/est-tenorio) gave helped me get what I needed.  But if multiple items are selected it will only deselect the first one.   To deselect all items that are currently selected I used

This logic is identical to [est.tenorio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2238519/est-tenorio), just with an explanation of what it its doing.

**Deselect all items**

```
for i in tree.selection():
        tree.selection_remove(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be done in one line.

```
tree.selection_remove(*tree.selection())
```