# Clear the selection after clicking a blank space

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm currently using python 3.9 and trying to clear the selection after clicking to  a blank space
It looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJLMi.gif).

This is my code:

```
fileTreeView = ttk.Treeview(m, name='fileTreeView')
fileTreeView['columns']=('name', 'datem', 'type', 'size', 'blankspace')
fileTreeView.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
fileTreeView.column('name',  width=60)
fileTreeView.column('datem',  width=60)
fileTreeView.column('type',  width=60)
fileTreeView.column('size',  width=60)
fileTreeView.column('blankspace', width=60)

fileTreeView.heading('#0')
fileTreeView.heading('name', text='Name')
fileTreeView.heading('datem', text='Date modified')
fileTreeView.heading('type', text='Type')
fileTreeView.heading('size', text='Size')
fileTreeView.heading('blankspace', text="")
```

I want when the blankspace column is clicked, it will clear the selection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593051/how-to-deselect-an-item-or-items-of-a-tkinter-ttk-treeview) your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the column being clicked inside the callback of `<Button-1>` event, if it is `blankspace` then clear the selection:

```py
def on_clicked(event):
    # get the column index being clicked
    col = fileTreeView.identify_column(event.x)
    # get the column name of the clicked column
    name = fileTreeView.column(col, 'id')
    if name == 'blankspace':
        # clear the selection
        fileTreeView.selection_set()
        # disable default mouse click handler
        return 'break'

fileTreeView.bind('<Button-1>', on_clicked)
```